# Translation of theme using child theme

Tags: functions, themes, translation

I have created a folder called “languages” in my child theme directory and added a: da_DK.po and a da_DK.mo file generated using POedit.
I have created a functions.php file in my child theme directory and added the following lines of code (as guided here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes):

```
<?php

/**
* Setup My Child Theme’s textdomain.
*
* Declare textdomain for this child theme.
* Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
*/
function my_child_theme_setup() {
load_child_theme_textdomain( ‘ifeaturepro5-child’, get_stylesheet_directory() . ‘/languages’ );
}
add_action( ‘after_setup_theme’, ‘my_child_theme_setup’ );
?>
```

This causes two issues:

#### 1. I cannot log into my wordpress admin area

#### 2. Trying to add a comment front end causes an error or a blank page.

When deleting the custom functions.php file in the child theme directory everything turn back to normal.

What have I entered wrong in my custom functions.php file shown above?

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Answer (score 1):

You are using weird quotes:

```
load_child_theme_textdomain( ‘ifeaturepro5-child’, get_stylesheet_directory() . ‘/languages’ );
}
add_action( ‘after_setup_theme’, ‘my_child_theme_setup’ );
```

use this:

```
load_child_theme_textdomain( 'ifeaturepro5-child', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
```

Comment: `functions.php` doesn't have to start with particular header, theme's header is in `style.css`.

Comment: @Rarst - You are right. I've updated my answer.